# Получение всех id, которыми помечены блоки "div" PHP

Tags: php, html, вывод

В общем, есть страница, которая формируется в зависимости от количества записей в бд.

```
<?php foreach ($Questions as $Quest) : ?>
                    <div id="<?=$Quest['id_rec']?>" class="panel__item <?= $Quest == current($Questions) ? ' active' : '' ?>">

                        <div class="name_question" align="center">
                            <h4>Вопрос №<?= $num ?> (<?= $Quest->name_quest; ?>)</h4>
                        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

                        <div class="text_question" align="center">
                            <?= $Quest->text_quest; ?>
                        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

                        <div class="answer">
                            <?php foreach ($Quest->squizqa as $Answer) { ?>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="<?=$Answer['id_rec']?>"> <?= $Answer->text_answer ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

                    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->
                <?php $num++; endforeach; ?>
```

По итогу страницу выглядит так:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div id="881" class="panel__item  active">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №1 (Арифметика)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Сколько будет <u><em><strong>2 + 2 * 2</strong></em></u> ?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="421"> 3 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="422"> 4 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="423"> 5 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="424"> 6 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="425"> 7 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="426"> 8 </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="861" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №2 (Подключение к Базе Данных)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Какая из предоставленных функций осуществляет соеденение с сервером MySQL?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="401"> mysql_connect </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="402"> mysql_client_ssl </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="403"> e_deprecated </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="862" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №3 (Двигатели)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Какие из предложанных двигателей существуют?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="404"> 1.9 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="405"> 2.0 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="406"> 2.2 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="407"> 5.7 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="408"> 7.1 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="409"> 8.2 TDI </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="841" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №4 (Подвиги Геракла)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Сколько подвигов совершил Геракл?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="382"> Двенадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="383"> Тринадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="381"> Одинадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="384"> Четырнадцать </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

</div>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/testsystem/testcomplete">Закончить тест</a>
```

Как мне при нажатии клавиши "Закончить тест", перейдя на другую страницу, считать все id из блоков 'div id=" " class="panel__item"'? По итогу перейдя на другую страницу, я хочу увидеть Id вопросов, на которые отвечал пользователь. Число блоков с вопросами на странице будет постоянно разным.

Comment: Запросить все div `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` и выбрать те у кого есть id.

Comment: используйте form

Comment: @nick_n_a как это сделать? как выбрать только id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам. При формировании и выводе данных на страницу, все ID записывал в массив с помощью скрипта:

```
<script>
   var IdQuestion = []; // Храним все ID вопросов
   document.querySelectorAll(".panel__item").forEach(function (n) {
      IdQuestion.push(n.id);
   })
   localStorage.setItem("ids", IdQuestion);
   console.log(localStorage.getItem("ids"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div id="881" class="panel__item  active">
        <form action="/testsystem/testcomplete" method="POST или GET">
        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №1 (Арифметика)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Сколько будет <u><em><strong>2 + 2 * 2</strong></em></u> ?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="421"> 3 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="422"> 4 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="423"> 5 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="424"> 6 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="425"> 7 </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="426"> 8 </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="861" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №2 (Подключение к Базе Данных)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Какая из предоставленных функций осуществляет соеденение с сервером MySQL?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="401"> mysql_connect </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="402"> mysql_client_ssl </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="403"> e_deprecated </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="862" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №3 (Двигатели)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Какие из предложанных двигателей существуют?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="404"> 1.9 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="405"> 2.0 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="406"> 2.2 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="407"> 5.7 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="408"> 7.1 TDI </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="409"> 8.2 TDI </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

    <div id="841" class="panel__item ">

        <div class="name_question" align="center">
            <h4>Вопрос №4 (Подвиги Геракла)</h4>
        </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

        <div class="text_question" align="center">
            <p>Сколько подвигов совершил Геракл?</p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

        <div class="answer">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="382"> Двенадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="383"> Тринадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="381"> Одинадцать </p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="384"> Четырнадцать </p>
        </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->
</form>
    </div> <!-- <div class="id_question"> -->

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Закончить тест</button>
```

Comment: Так, и что мне это даст? Допустим я добавил форму с методом Пост или Гет, а дальше как?

Comment: А вы точно программист? Обычно таких вопросов не должно возникать, что делать с методом `POST` или `GET`, вам данные нужно передать как-то на другую страницу, так вот я вам сказал как их передать. Дальше по средствам `РНР` или еще как, вы их должны вывести на следующей странице ну или же по средствам `jQuery` или `JavaScript`, как вам удобней или может вообще какой другой язык вы используете я без понятия...